# How to bind() on all ports?

Tags: c, sockets, port

I want to use a socket with as port, any port available. But I don't really know how to do it

Here's what I tried :

```
s_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
s_in.sin_port = htons(0);
s_in.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

Any idea ?

Comment: If you assign port number 0 as you do in your code example, bind will pick a free port number for you.

Comment: What's wrong with the code above? That looks fine.

Comment: The problem is it's taking a random port if i'm not wrong with `htons(0). But I want it to take all ports, not just one at random.

Comment: You can't, and you don't want to. If this was possible, no other service could run.

Comment: @nookonee You need to explain your use case much better. I don't think anybody understands what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't. One solution is to use port translation. If you're using Linux you can do something such as:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 128.66.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 128.66.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1:65535 -j DNAT --to-destination 128.66.0.1:11944
```

This will map all ports except (except port 22) to port 11944. Then you only have to bind to port 11944 in your program.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're trying to do. If you wish to receive data, you must bind a socket to a port. That's the purpose of ports. You *can* set up a "raw socket", but that means you then have to handle the transport layer headers yourself: you can't just forget about them.

If you just wish to send a UDP datagram, you can `sendto` without prior `bind`. Any available port will be used as the source.

Answer (score -3):

If you're looking to take any port available, you may just loop from 1024 to 65355, trying to bind your socket on the first available.

If you want to capture EVERY PORT, what you're looking for is a RAW SOCKET.

More info here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket

And here for linux : http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw